matplotlib: canvas buffer size changes after plt.pause?
minimum code to reproduce
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5, 5))

fig.canvas.draw()
len1 = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
plt.pause(0.01)
len2 = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))

fig.canvas.draw()
len3 = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
plt.pause(0.01)
len4 = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))

print(len1, len2, len3, len4)

output: 1000000 2250000 2250000 2250000
expected: 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000
Question
length of canvas buffer changed after I call plt.pause, and do not change even if I call another draw method. Is this a bug or is it designed this way?
Background (my purpose)
I am trying to make simple animation using draw() method. Instead of FuncAnimation API, this solution has better control when you want to stop the animation (plt.ion() enabled, so some computations can run in background). So, with plt.ion(), I need to call plt.pause so that it does not block the entire thread.
Now when I want to turn the animation to video, I try to acquire the buffer of the canvas, and face this "buffer size question"
Environment
tested in two case:

Python 3.10.14 + matplotlib 3.9.0
Python 3.11.5 + matplotlib 3.7.2


Is your screen hi dpi?  Maybe at 1.25 scaling?

Based on @Jody Klymak's comment, I partly figured out.
To be concise,
it's related to the computer settings of display.
Before plt.pause
buffer size can be exactly calculated with formula size=channel\*(fig_width\*dpi)\*(fig_height\*dpi).
For example, a figure created by plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100) should have a buffer size = 1e6, calculated by 4*(5*100)*(5*100).
After plt.pause
buffer size may be affected by your computer settings.
For example, as mentioned in the question, buffer sized is multiplied by 2.25, because my pc sets the scale of text, application and others as 150%, and 1.5*1.5=2.25.
However, this is probably not the only factor that affects buffer size. In extreme cases, such as plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100000), buffer size may be compressed because the image size is too large. Similarly, buffer size may also be expanded because the image size is too small. In these cases, the scale ratio is related to more factors, and the pattern is unclear yet.

Here is a solution that I made in Jupyter Notebook. The buffer length is constant but not 1000000, but rather 840528 Buffer length after plt.pause(): 840528 but if I understand it right you are interested in constancy rather than a given figure.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

data = {
    'x': np.linspace(0, 10, 100),
    'y': np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)  
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'b-')
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

fig.canvas.draw()
len1 = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
print(f'Initial buffer length: {len1}')

def animate():
    for i in range(1, len(df) + 1):
        line.set_data(df['x'][:i], df['y'][:i])
        ax.set_title(f"Frame {i}")
        clear_output(wait=True)
        display(fig)
        plt.pause(0.1)
        buffer_len = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
        print(f'Buffer length after plt.pause(): {buffer_len}')

animate()

fig.canvas.draw()
len_final = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
print(f'Final buffer length: {len_final}')

plt.close(fig)  

which gives as a snapshot

If you are not using Jupyter Notebook the code reduces to
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'x': np.linspace(0, 10, 100),
    'y': np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)  
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'b-')
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

fig.canvas.draw()
len1 = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
print(f'Initial buffer length: {len1}')

def animate():
    for i in range(1, len(df) + 1):
        line.set_data(df['x'][:i], df['y'][:i])
        ax.set_title(f"Frame {i}")
        fig.canvas.draw()  
        buffer_len = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
        print(f'Buffer length after plt.pause(): {buffer_len}')
        plt.pause(0.1)  

animate()

fig.canvas.draw()
len_final = len(np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.buffer_rgba(), dtype='uint8'))
print(f'Final buffer length: {len_final}')

plt.ioff()  
plt.show() 

